# Firefox tab shortcut keys

Tags: firefox

In Firefox (mostly for Windows), I know I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> to change to a certain tab. I have 10 "app tabs" opened at any given time, on top of my other tabs. Is there a way to use the keyboard to navigate with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`number`</kbd> shortcut, but not have it include App Tabs?

Yes, I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp/Down/TAB</kbd>, but that will take too long sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean by "app tab?"

Comment: App tab is how I can have web apps open everytime I open Firefox

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how I can have web apps open."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this addon([`Numberedtabs`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/numberedtabs/)) work for you.

> Displays the number of the tab in the title of the tab. Now you can switch tabs quickly in firefox with Ctrl-[1-8] or Cmd-[1-8].

### Update

Use the [`AppTabs Plus addon`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/apptabs-plus/).

Check the option `Exclude from tab-switching`.

[image]